# Problema com partilha do Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

Tenho um script `javascript` que me partilha determinados posts na minha pagina em que o conteúdo que partilha e gerado automaticamente da base de dados.

Funciona bem, o único problema que estou a ter, é com a descrição quando chamo a variável que contém o texto e o script deixa de funcionar.
Coloquei o mesmo texto mas directamente na página e reparei que com parágrafos ele acusa erro então coloquei o texto seguido sem nenhum parágrafo e funciona bem.

Agora só o que preciso resolver é que o sistema corrija esse problema automaticamente mas já tentei com o `strip_tags` e não resolveu.

**Script**

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#share_fb_<?= $row_posts_home->id; ?>", function(e) { 
  FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'http://sabeonde.pt',
    picture: 'http://sabeonde.pt/gtm/anexos/posts_home/<?= $row_posts_home_anexos->id_anexo ?>.<?= $row_posts_home_anexos->tipo ?>',
    name: '<?= $row_posts_home->titulo; ?>',
    caption: 'SabeOnde',
    description: '<?= strip_tags($row_posts_home->descricao); ?>'
  });
});
</script>
```

Sim o problema e na `description`

Exemplo:

se eu colocar direto como o php irá imprimir

description: 'Uma das mais aclamadas e respeitadas vozes portuguesas do fado.
Com mais de 30 discos de platina e uma das estrelas mais aplaudidas do circuito mundial de World Music, Mariza regressa ao Multiusos de Guimarães no dia 21 de março de 2015.Considerada uma “artista completa, capaz de ‘hipnotizar’ uma plateia inteira com o fado cantado com alma”, Mariza recebeu recentemente o prémio Womex 2014 em Santiago de Compostela.Mariza já esgotou as mais prestigiadas salas de todo o mundo – Carnegie Hall em Nova Iorque, Ópera de Sidne.';

Ele já nao aceita e o script já nao funciona

Se puser assim ja funciona

descrition: Uma das mais aclamadas e respeitadas vozes portuguesas do fado.Com mais de 30 discos de platina e uma das estrelas mais aplaudidas do circuito mundial de World Music, Mariza regressa ao Multiusos de Guimarães no dia 21 de março de 2015.Considerada uma “artista completa, capaz de ‘hipnotizar’ uma plateia inteira com o fado cantado com alma”, Mariza recebeu recentemente o prémio Womex 2014 em Santiago de Compostela.Mariza já esgotou as mais prestigiadas salas de todo o mundo – Carnegie Hall em Nova Iorque, Ópera de Sidne.

Comment: O problema é no description? Poste um exemplo de como fica este script após o PHP escrever.

Comment: Já coloquei o exemplo

Comment: Aparece algum erro no console?

Comment: Não aparece nenhum erro